# .htacces rewrite rule not work

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website. I want to my site seo friendly. For that I used .htacces rewrite rule for making custom seo friendly url.

I want when I put url i.e http://nila.mobi/services it will shows the content of file http://nila.mobi/services.php.

There have same page structure like that. I used the code on .htacces file which I write on bellow.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Where am I wrong. Please help me.

Comment: what does `RewriteLog`say..

Answer (score 1):

Reorder your rules and add `L` flag:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its perfectly working. I really appreciate your quick response.